# function pointer used in struct in C

Tags: c++, c, arrays, struct, function-pointers

Could anyone explain the following syntax of code for structures in C ?

```
struct { 
  Fn *pmq;
}
service_MQ[] = 
{
   NULL
   #define BUILd_SVC_MQ(name , func) , (Fn*) Func
   #include<mqsvctable.h>
};
```

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_structures.htm

Comment: You have a #define and a #include in the middle of a structure declaration??!!  It may well be legal, but ...

Comment: @ratednitesh Did you perhaps mean to type: `#define BUILD_SVC_MQ(name, func) , (Fn*) func`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- There is a structure with only member as a pointer (possibly to a
  function)
- There is an x-header file `mqsvctable.h` containing list of functions
  under `BUILd_SVC_MQ` macro. Something like

```
BUILd_SVC_MQ("clear", clear_screen)
BUILd_SVC_MQ("delete", delete_something)
```

- You use this [x-macro header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) to prepare an array of your struct.